# Как сохранять Fragment при переходе?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть FrameLayout. В методе onCreate я сразу вызываю метод fragmentReplace() и передаю ему HomeFragment. В HomeFragment хранится RecyclerView. Когда я через BottomNavigationView перехожу на другой фрагмент и обратно, все что было в HomeFragment удаляется.

Метод fragmentReplace()

```
public void fragmentReplace(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Я раньше создавал глобальный View и передавал ему HomeFragment, а потом заново его брал когда он был мне нужен. Но мне кажется этот способ не правильный. В статьях в интернете я не смог понять или найти нужную мне информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если RecyclerView хранится в разметке, из которой вы делаете View в HomeFragment.onCreateView, то он удаляется вместе с этой созданной View при откреплении HomeFragment. Когда вы снова прицепляете фрагмент, onCreateView отрабатывает снова, RecyclerView в нем есть, но он пустой, нужно снова прикреплять к нему адаптер. Сделать это можно в onViewCreated, onStart или onResume. Почитайте про сохранение состояний фрагментов, там есть пара способов, какой-нибудь из них вам поможет.

Ну, до кучи, чтобы сохранить прокрутку RecyclerView, вытащите из нее LayoutManager и сохраните его состояние, примерно так:

```
private Parcelable savedState = null
    @Override 
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        savedState = ((LinearLayoutManager)list.layoutManager).onSaveInstanceState()
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        ((LinearLayoutManager)list.layoutManager).onRestoreInstanceState(savedState)

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно прошло много времени. Я просто забыл написать об этом)